# what does 節目のご祈祷 mean

Tags: meaning, words, manga

I read a manga named 神様の御用人.

https://www.cmoa.jp/title/116209/
(page 28)

I don't understand 厄払いや**節目のご祈祷**も行っております. I searched the vocab in jisho but it doesn't make any sense.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: To avoid having this question closed as off-topic, can you please include your best attempt at translation?

Answer (score 1):

This 節目 vaguely refers to important life events such as 入学/卒業, 成人, 就職/転職, 住宅購入 and 結婚, but one of the most important is probably [七五三](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shichi-Go-San) today. In other words, one enters the next life "stage" after a 節目, and it's a good timing to thank and pray for Japanese *kami*. The kanji 節 means "section", and it's the same 節 as in 季節.

There is no charge if you just visit a shrine and pray by yourself (aside from small *saisen*), but most shrines offer paid services to have a priest pray only for you. [This](https://kanmuri.com/topics/691) is an example of a price list.